# How to change table data into three different values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Is there a ways to update a SQL table using query in three different value when certain condition is met?

What I am trying to do is change quarter values into three or more different values for diversity of quarters.

Here is my table

[image]

and I want this to be

```
1000    Fall2011     M2:00AM      34
1000    Winter2011   W4:50PM     723
1000    Spring2011   T8:00PM      34
1000    Summer2011   M8:00PM      34
.
.
.
```

Comment: why does the value of `quarter` change from Fall2011 to Winter2011 in the second line? What are the criteria for changing the quarter names?

Comment: yea I just want to modify rows to have different quarter value. [Summer, Spring,Fall, Winter] + anywhere 2005 ~20012.

Comment: Pick one of MySQL or Postgres. Asking for both is confusing the issue.

Comment: Why you are not using 3 update statements